# How can I keep using the command prompt after executing a .cmd file in Windows?

Tags: cmd

After I double clicked a .cmd file and it executed successfully, it just closed the command prompt window. Even if I add `pause` to the end it also closes after I hit any key. So is there a way to let me keep using the command prompt, just as if I got the window from running `cmd`?

Comment: Would it be ok to add `cmd.exe` at the end of your script? It does not exactly keep the current shell open but you end up with a open shell.

Comment: A double click on a `.cmd` file results in execution of `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /c "Full Path\BatchFile.cmd"`. The option `/c` means execute the command line after this option and then __close__. There can be opened a command prompt window and run the batch file from within the command prompt window. In this case `cmd.exe` is implicit started like on using option `/k` to __keep__ `cmd.exe` running after each execution of a command, executable or batch file.

Comment: There can be used in in batch file at top below `@echo off` something like `@setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion & for /F "tokens=1,2" %%G in ("!CMDCMDLINE!") do @endlocal & if /I "%%~nG" == "cmd" if /I "%%~H" == "/c" start "%~n0" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K %0 %* & exit /B`. This command line checks if the Windows command processor was started with second argument being the option `/c` and in this case starts one more `cmd.exe` with the options `/D` and `/K` and the original arguments and exits current batch file processing.

Comment: So the `cmd.exe` instance started with `/c` on double clicking the batch file closes immediately and a new instance of `cmd.exe` is started with option `/k` to process the double clicked batch file and keeps finally running. There is not started a new instance of `cmd.exe` if there is first opened a command prompt window without option `/c` and then executed the batch file from within the command prompt window.

Comment: You might read somewhere to just use `cmd /k` at end of the batch file. This is a not good advice as it results in keeping two `cmd.exe` instances running, the first one started with `/c` on double clicking the batch file and the second one started by the batch file. The first `cmd.exe` started with `/c` keeps running because of the second `cmd.exe` started with option `/k` keeps also running until the user enters `exit` or closes the console window. That is of course not good.

Comment: The problem with using just `cmd /k` at end of the batch file is that on running the batch file from within a command prompt window multiple times, there is always started at end one more `cmd.exe` which keeps running. So if such a batch file is run 10 times from within a Windows command prompt window, there are finally 11 `cmd.exe` instances running and the user has to execute 10 times `exit` to get closed all additional `cmd.exe` processes and get back to the initial `cmd.exe` started for the Windows command prompt window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very simple.

Add the following line to the end of your code:
`start /b cmd`

Comment: That is as bad as using `cmd /K` at end of the batch file. It starts always a new cmd.exe instance with omitting option `/K` and therefore being used implicit by the started `cmd.exe` even on batch file not being executed with a double click in Windows File Explorer, but from within a command prompt window. Correction: This command line is even worse than using `cmd /K` at end of the batch file as it results in output of copyright message by new started `cmd.exe` and no prompt is displayed after entering `exit` on batch file being executed from an already opened command prompt window.

Comment: You can simply write it like this:
`start /b cmd /k cls` or `start /b cmd >nul`

Comment: That is no real solution. The goal of original poster is most likely that the output produced by the batch file is still visible and so `cls` is not good. This also does not solve the problems I wrote if the batch file is not executed with a double click from Windows File Explorer, but from within a command prompt window. A batch file programmer cannot control how a user of the batch file starts the execution of the batch file. For that reason it is advisable for a batch file programmer not expecting that a user runs the batch file always like the programmer thinks or hopes.

Comment: The single line posted by me in a comment above uses the `cmd.exe` as started already on batch file being executed from within a command prompt window or with a shortcut file which runs `cmd.exe` with option `/k` and appended the fully qualified file name of the batch file. Such a shortcut file is the preferred method to start a command prompt window with a special environment often used by Python programmers. However, any solution is not good if any user wants to call the batch file of original poster ever from within another batch file or an executable.